# Passing parameter using action link in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two views category and product I retrieve products by passing category Id and I want to  implement search function in my products view. when I try to pass category id and search string
in my controller method search form submit not working if I pass search string alone then its working. how to pass both parameter in controller method. or should I use partial view for this

Category view:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink(
            @item.Category, 
            "Products", "
            Home", 
            new { cid = @item.CategoryId, search = UrlParameter.Optional}, 
            null)
    </li>
}
```

Product view:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Products", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <b>Search:</b> @Html.TextBox("search")<input type="submit" value="search" />
}
```

Controller method:

```
public ActionResult Products( string search,int cid) 
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
    {
        var ser = db.searchPro(search);
        return View(ser);
    }
    else
    {
        var Pro = db.getProducts(cid);
        return View(Pro);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the param type to Nullable, because when you submit from product search view, there's no 'cid'

```
public ActionResult Products( string search,int? cid)
```

Comment: Thank you very much Teddy for the instant response..Its working